# How to build Microsoft and Mac OS App with Compose for Desktop with the right approach

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I need to develop a desktop app for Windows and Mac OS with [Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/)
I will use the Kotlin language to design the UI.
But I need guidance on following points:

1. Which languages will be required for the core logic / calculations / network client, etc. in the desktop app ?
2. Can we write the entire Microsoft desktop app in Kotlin (Compose for Desktop)
3. Can we use Android classes like `Fragment`, `ViewModels`, `Room` in Compose for Desktop ?
4. If we cannot use Android classes in desktop app then, where do we write the code which we write in `ViewModel` classes in Android ? How to structure the code and packages
5. What is the best architecture for Desktop app which are being built with Compose or Desktop. ?
   I could not find any architecture diagram for Desktop Compose App
6. Can we use Jnuit and Espresso for writing UI and Instrumented tests in Compose for Desktop ?

**Note**:

1. I have gone through the official documentation of compose desktop.
   I also went though the code of samples and multiple blogs, but the above queries are not answered clearly.

Hence I need your guidance

Answer (score 1):

1,2 — I guess that any JVM-compatible language would be fine.
3,4 — https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/discussions/1587

> You should abstract from androidx ViewModel creating a pure Kotlin ViewModel delegate that can be injected into android ViewModel.
> So in this case androidx ViewModel will play the role of wrapper over multiplatform implementation.
> But keep in mind that there is no component's lifecycle or navigation ecosystem like in Android world. For this purpose, you can use Decompose library.

I am not an expert in Compose for Desktop, so I would prefer not to answer the last two questions. Also, I would recommend you to search for answers in the [#compose-desktop](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C01D6HTPATV) channel of the Kotlin official Slack workspace(get an invite [here](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up)).